Magento Admin Panel Keeps Loading (Macbook Pro ) (installation done by brew)(permission and deploy all fine)
cat nginx.conf (my defualt nginx.conf)(/opt/homebrew/etc/nginx) 

#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

 #error_log  logs/error.log; 
 #error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
 #error_log  logs/error.log  info;

 #pid        logs/nginx.pid;

 events {
   worker_connections  1024;
  }


 http {
  include       mime.types;
  default_type  application/octet-stream;

#log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
#                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
#                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

#access_log  logs/access.log  main;

sendfile        on;
#tcp_nopush     on;

#keepalive_timeout  0;
keepalive_timeout  65;

#gzip  on;

server {
    listen       8080;
    server_name  localhost;

    #charset koi8-r;

    #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        root   html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   html;
    }

    # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
    #}

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    root           html;
    #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
    #    include        fastcgi_params;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #    deny  all;
    #}
}


# another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
#
#server {
#    listen       8000;
#    listen       somename:8080;
#    server_name  somename  alias  another.alias;

#    location / {
#        root   html;
#        index  index.html index.htm;
#    }
#}


# HTTPS server
#
#server {
#    listen       443 ssl;
#    server_name  localhost;

#    ssl_certificate      cert.pem;
#    ssl_certificate_key  cert.key;

#    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
#    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

#    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
#    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

#    location / {
#        root   html;
#        index  index.html index.htm;
#    }
#}
include servers/*;
}

Here is My Configuration File (/opt/homebrew/etc/nginx/servers)
server {
listen 80;
server_name dev.test.co.nz;
root /usr/local/var/www/test/pub;
index index.php index.html;
 location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    autoindex off;
 }
 location /static/ {
  if (!-f $request_filename) {
      rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
  }
}
location ~ \.php$ {
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass localhost:9000; 
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
}
location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
}
}


already remove the static/  pub/ (kept the .htaccess)
run all the magento command like - deploy and all

can you please let me know what is the issue  (same is working fine on ubuntu machine)

